# Display two filtered pivot tables in the same sheet on separate worksheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

On excel 2007, in one sheet i have 2 pivot tables created by the first image table below

[image]

and i have create two pivot tables in the same worksheet as you can see in the second image below, and i have choose all stores, now i know i can use option Show Report Filtered pages with the field stores if i have one pivot table, but can i do the same with 2 pivot tables simultaneously?

[image]

For example to choose both pivot tables and create with Show Report Filtered pages new sheets like in the third image but with both tables in it?

If there is a way with formula,functions any solution not with VBA or macro.

[image]

Comment: Sorry rong flag, yes i try it but can't be.And i want a simpler way if there is, an if anyone has an idea about what i try to do,and i have 2 pivot tables in the same sheet and this is the sheet where from i want to create what i have expained already. Thanks for your observation about the flag if you can't help me ok relax.

Answer (score 0):

If you upgrade to excel 2010, you'll be able to use Slicers for that purpose. In Excel 2007, you will have to use macros to achieve a similar effect.

Comment: I know that about Excel 2010 but i search for a kind of solution in 2007, but i have search a lot and i can't find a simple solution and you are right macros would be a solution but the person i want to help need a solution without macros because he want for me to explain him how will he can doing the same alone with a simple way he can't learn macros or VBA but he must use Excel 2007 and make what i have ask.Thanks for your answer.